# How can I recreate a Django project's database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I dropped MySQL database used by my Django project by a mistake. Fortunately, it's only my development environment. How can I recreate the database and all the tables?

When I do `python manage.py syncdb` it fails with

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'myproject'")
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create the database within MySQL before running syncdb:

```
mysql> create database myproject;
```

Answer (score 2):

`syncdb` doesn't create the database for you. You'll need to go into your MySQL shell and do `CREATE DATABASE myproject;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new database and configure permissions. http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user